# Free street parking options for unlimited time in Bratislava?

Tags: automobiles, slovakia, bratislava

I am looking for free parking options in Bratislava.
Is there free parking along the river, near the UFO bridge?

Ideally I'd like to park somewhere for an unlimited time at a reasonably safe spot and subsequently switch to public transport.

Answer (score 4):

Bratislava's municipal parking company [provides a map](http://www.bps.sk/mapa/) of the resident-only parking zone. Parking there generally requires either a resident's permit (which you obviously won't have) or an hourly fee.

[image]]

Therefore your best bet is to park a little bit to the west of the UFO bridge, where the resident parking zone ends. One example is [Zizkova](https://goo.gl/maps/sgXFr) street.